# how to save a column vector in an iteration process to a text file

Tags: python

I need to save a column vector obtained in an iteration to a text file using python.

This is what I have been using till now

```
savetxt('displacement{0}.out'.format(globdat.cycle), a, delimiter=',', fmt='%10.4e',)
```

globdat.cycle is used as a count so that in each iteration a separate file is made.

requirement - I do not require separate files but a single file which contains all the vectors corresponding to each iteration.

eg - iteration 1 values  =  [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]' and iteration 2 values = [ a c v b f h ]'

my text file should look something similar to

1,a

2,c

3,v

4,b

5,f

6,h

I would much appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: What does savetxt do, what is a, what is delimiter, and what is fmt?  You've given us one line of code and only told us about one of the variables.

Comment: Hi Paul, well all of them apart from 'a' ('a' is the variable I save in the text file) are in the savetxt command format in numpy. So they have their usual meaning.

Comment: Couldn't you just make a file in the conventional way with a call to open, then write each line in? If its just a text file you don't need anything else. Formatting each string to look like the column you want before writing it to the file is the only thing left to do after that.

Comment: Hi Adam, Could you please give the code segment.